# Django model field contains list of tuples - how to unpack in template

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples in a Django model field called color_palette. Its set of 5 RGB color values from image.

```
[(29, 28, 28), 
(239, 244, 244), 
(158, 165, 172), 
(89, 162, 203), 
(106, 141, 169)]
```

I want to unpack these in the template along with other model fields.

```
{% for screenshot in country.screenshots_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ screenshot.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ country.name }}"  class="thumbnail" width="150" height="150" style="border:none;"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I can get the entire list of tuples to show on template by using:

```
{% for screenshot in country.screenshots_set.all %}
    {{ screenshot.color_palette }}
    <img src="{{ screenshot.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ country.name }}"  class="thumbnail" width="150" height="150" style="border:none;"/>
{% endfor %}
```

But haven't yet figured out method to unpack them in the template.

I have tried this which splits on list characters

```
<ul>
    {% for color in screenshot.color_palette %}    
         <li>{{ color.0 }}</li>
         <li>{{ color.1 }}</li>
         <li>{{ color.2 }}</li>
         <li>{{ color.3 }}</li>
         <li>{{ color.4 }}</li>  
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and this attempt which results in split at all characters in the list:

```
 <ul>
     {% for color in screenshot.color_palette %}
         <li>{{ color }}</li>
     {% endfor %}    
 </ul>
```

Is this even possible the way I am trying to do it?

The solutions for unpacking tuple that aren't working for me are for lists that are generated in the view and sent to template.

I guess it is because the thing I am trying to iterate through is a string while the view would send an iterable object.

Comment: Can you post your model please?

Comment: It looks as though `color_palette` being passed to the template is a string, and not a list of tuples. Can you post the code that is generating the context and also verify that it really is a list and not a string?

Comment: Ah ok. wishful thinking. Yes the color_palette field is a text data type. I guess I should look to see if it can be type list. Any other methods to get this done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a model method and use it whenever necessary.

```
from ast import literal_eval

class Screenshot(models.Model):
    colors = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def colors_list(self):
        # literal_eval, turns your string into an actual list of tuples
        colors = literal_eval(self.colors)

        return colors
```

assuming you render your template with `render(request, {'screenshot': Screenshot.objects.first()}`, you can get your colors list with `{{ screenshot.colors_list }}` in your template.

Comment: Great worked perfectly. I used `def colors_list(self):` 
        `colors = literal_eval(self.color_palette)`
        `return colors` and then in template looped through `{% for color in screenshot.colors_list %}` to retrieve tuple items to create `rgb({{ color.0 }},{{ color.1 }},{{ color.2 }})`